# generating data with two variables

Tags: python, string, for-loop, typeerror

I'm trying to generate a file, given the number of cars (`i`) and the arrival time (`j`), but I can't make the code work properly.
For example if want 5 vehicles between depart 0 and 60 [i=5,j=(0,60)] generate something like these:

```
<routes>
<vehicle id="left_0" type="typeWE" route="left" depart="8" />
<vehicle id="left_1" type="typeWE" route="left" depart="17" />
<vehicle id="right_2" type="typeWE" route="right" depart="39" />
<vehicle id="up_3" type="typeNS" route="up" depart="50" color="1,0,0"/>
<vehicle id="left_4" type="typeWE" route="left" depart="58" />
<routes>
```

This is the code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
import optparse
import subprocess
import random

def generate_routefile():
    random.seed(47)
    N = 800  # number of cars
    M = 1600 # demand per second from different directions
    pWE = 1. / 10
    pNS = 1. / 30

    with open("800_r.rou.xml", "w") as routes:
        print("<routes>", file=routes)
        lastVeh = 0
        vehNr = 0

        for i in range(N):
            for j in range(M):
                if random.uniform(0, 1) < pWE:
                    print('    <vehicle id="right_%i" type="typeWE" route="right" depart="%%j" />' % (
                        vehNr, i, j), file=routes)
                    vehNr += 1
                    lastVeh = i
                if random.uniform(0, 1) < pEW:
                    print('    <vehicle id="left_%i" type="typeWE" route="left" depart="%i" />' % (
                        vehNr, i), file=routes)
                    vehNr += 1
                    lastVeh = i
                if random.uniform(0, 1) < pNS:
                    print('    <vehicle id="down_%i" type="typeNS" route="down" depart="%i" color="1,0,0"/>' % (
                        vehNr, i), file=routes)
                    vehNr += 1
                    lastVeh = i
                if random.uniform(0, 1) < pNS:
                    print('    <vehicle id="up_%i" type="typeNS" route="up" depart="%i" color="1,0,0"/>' % (
                        vehNr, i), file=routes)
                    vehNr += 1
                    lastVeh = i

        print("</routes>", file=routes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    generate_routefile()`
```

The error is `line 36, in generate_routefile
    vehNr, i, j), file=routes)
ValueError: unsupported format character 'j' (0x6a) at index 64`

I'm trying to add a variable for the arrival time of the vehicles (depart), the code work only when`i` is the only variable.

This works, but whit this code i can only define the depart value:

```
for i in range(N):
    if random.uniform(0, 1) < pWE:
        print('    <vehicle id="right_%i" type="typeWE" route="right" depart="%i" />' % (
            vehNr, i), file=routes)
        vehNr += 1
        lastVeh = i
```

but this doesn't, but in this i would define the numbers of cars and the depart time:

```
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        if random.uniform(0, 1) < pWE:
            print('    <vehicle id="right_%i" type="typeWE" route="right" depart="%j" />' % (
                vehNr, i, j), file=routes)
            vehNr += 1
            lastVeh = i
```

Comment: I have no idea what SUMO is. Regardless, where exactly is the error occurring? Please [edit] your question and add the full traceback you're getting to it.

Comment: You are using %j in a format string (next to `depart=`), and that isn't supported. Please the correct code for your variable type (maybe %d)

Comment: Which Python version are you running? Instead of %s, %d, %i you can now use `f''` or the older but familiar `str.format()`.

Comment: you may use format. `'    <vehicle id="right_{}" type="typeWE" route="right" depart="{}"'.format(i, j)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I see what you mean now.

`%i` is a placeholder for an integer meanwhile `%j` is not recognized in python. This has nothing to do with i or j.

Using `%i` twice is not a problem.

---

And if we look carefully at the code that does not work:

```
print('    <vehicle id="right_%i" type="typeWE" route="right" depart="%j" />' % (
                vehNr, i, j), file=routes)
```

You are trying to insert 3 values but you only have two potential placeholders (%i, %j) (remember %j is an incorrect one).

Comment: you are right using %i twice is not a problem. but i want to use two variable i and j, and the i variable have to create 100 vehicles rute and the j varible have to take a number between 0 and 1600. Any suggestion how to do it ?

Comment: @AlexanderMartínez Sorry but I'm not understanding what you mean 100 %. Can you try to update your question?

Comment: The `i` in `%i` refers to the type of value to be displayed (integer); it has *absolutely nothing* to do with the name of the variable being displayed.  `"%i" % j` is perfectly valid code.